# How to get Outlook appointments from a given date in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to display Outlook Calendar appointments from a given date in a MessageBox. Unfortunately the code I am using does not show any appointments for today. If i change my code to 
`sfilter = "[Start] >= '" & startDate & "' "` 
then i get todays appointments with all future appointments for other dates. I want to only show appointments for the specified date.

The date selection is from a `UserForm` called `cmDates.srtDate.Value`

`sFilter` is the variable I am using the hold the date filter throughout the code

**Code**

```
Public Function getOutlookAppointments() As String
    Dim oOutlook              As Object
    Dim oNS                   As Object
    Dim oAppointments         As Object
    Dim oFilterAppointments   As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem      As Object
    Dim bOutlookOpened        As Boolean
   ' Dim rslt                  As String
    Dim sfilter               As String
    Dim startDate             As Date
    Dim displayText As String
    Dim start As Date
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
        Err.Clear
        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bOutlookOpened = False    'Outlook was not already running, we had to start it
    Else
        bOutlookOpened = True    'Outlook was already running
    End If
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    DoEvents

    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    startDate = cmDates.srtDate.value
    'Apply a filter so we don't waste our time going through old stuff if we don't need to.
    sfilter = "[Start] = '" & startDate & "' "
    Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.Items.Restrict(sfilter)

    For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilterAppointments
     getOutlookAppointments = getOutlookAppointments & oFilterAppointments.Count & " appointment(s) found" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & oAppointmentItem.Subject & vbCrLf & oAppointmentItem.start & vbCrLf & oAppointmentItem.End & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

      'displayText = displayText & oAppointmentItem.Subject

    Next

    MsgBox prompt:=getOutlookAppointments, _
    Title:="Appointments for"


    If bOutlookOpened = False Then    'Since we started Outlook, we should close it now that we're done
        oOutlook.Quit 'There seems to be a delay in this action taking place, but does eventually take place
    End If

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
    Set oFilterAppointments = Nothing
    Set oAppointments = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: GetFutureOutlookEvents" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit

    outlookDates = False
End Function
```

Comment: MS Help for the `.Restrict` method suggests you need to format the date as a string.  So maybe:  `sfilter = "[Start] = '" & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' "`  Seems to work here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld still getting 0 for the results even though i have appointments for today

Comment: Can't help.  Your code, with the formatted string as shown, works here.  The only thing I changed was `startDate =  some_known_date_with_appointments`, and I commented out the last line, as `outlookDates` is not declared.  Are you sure `startDate` contains a real date?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes, startDate is a date, I have even declared it as Date. It is being passed on from a userform textbox

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i made a dummy appointment for 07/16/2019 at 12:00 AM and it shows my appointment that I created. Must be something to do with the time

Comment: Then I suggest you set your filter as a range:  eg. `start >=startdate and start < startdate+1`  with the appropriate formatting of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Your restriction should have two parts - `Start > today's midnight`, and `Start < tomorrow's midnight`. You only have the first part.

Also keep in mind that if you want instances of the recurring activities (and not just the master appointments), you need to use the `Items.IncludeRecurrences` property - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences

Comment: i wrote out `sfilter = "[Start] < '" & startDate & "' " And "[Start] > '" & startDate & "'"` now i am getting an error. Not sure if I wrote out correctly

Comment: What is the exact error? Your date must be formatted correctly, and the second value must be the first value plus 24 hours.

Comment: my function returns a blank answer, i have formatted like so: `sfilter = "[Start] = '" & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' " And "[Start] = '" & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")`

Comment: Do not use "=" - it will never match because of the round-off errors. You must use `<` and `>`.. And the second date must be greater than the first one - you must use a range.

Comment: @ Dmitry Streblechenko I changed my code but the function remains blank when i add the second part. How can i increase my second date by 1? `sfilter = "[Start] > '" & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn") And "[Start] < '" & Format(startDate + 1, "ddddd h:nn") & "'"`

Comment: Are you sure the date/time format is right? ddddd is for displaying the long date fromat in VBA. What is the value of the sfilter after you build it?

Comment: after the build the value is empty

Comment: The value of the sfilter variable is an empty string?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196491/discussion-between-jose-and-dmitry-streblechenko).

Comment: I would prefer to continue in the comments - the discussion is still relevant for other people who might run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects:

1. To retrieve all Outlook appointment items from the folder that meets the predefined condition, you need to [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866960.aspx) the items in ascending order and set the [IncludeRecurrences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866969.aspx) to true. You will not catch recurrent appointments if you don’t do this before using the `Restrict` method!
2. Microsoft doesn’t recommend using the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868906.aspx) property in case you set the `IncludeRecurrences` property. The `Count` property may return unexpected results and cause an infinite loop.
3. Although dates and times are typically stored with a `Date` format, the `Find` and `Restrict` methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function available in VBA. So, you must specify the date in the format which Outlook understand.

```
     Format(youDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")
```

For example, here is a sample VB.NET code:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Diagnostics
' ...
Private Sub RestrictCalendarItems(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim dtEnd As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, _
                                         DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 0, 0)
    Dim restrictCriteria As String = "[Start]<=""" + dtEnd.ToString("g") + """" + _
                                     " AND [End]>=""" + DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + """"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim appItem As Outlook._AppointmentItem = Nothing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim item As Object = Nothing
    Try
        strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        folderItems = folder.Items
        folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
        folderItems.Sort("[Start]")
        resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria)
        item = resultItems.GetFirst()
        Do
            If Not IsNothing(item) Then
                If (TypeOf (item) Is Outlook._AppointmentItem) Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    appItem = item
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                          " Start: " + appItem.Start.ToString() + _
                                          " Subject: " + appItem.Subject + _
                                          " Location: " + appItem.Location)
                End If
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)
                item = resultItems.GetNext()
            End If
        Loop Until IsNothing(item)
        If (strBuilder.Length > 0) Then
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " _
                             + folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If
    catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(folderItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems)
        If Not IsNothing(resultItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItems)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)